# How to get the character limit length used in mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysqli, codeigniter-3

Suppose you have a table in MySQL

```
+----+---------+--------------+
| No |  Name   |    Type      |
+----+---------+--------------+
| 1  | nav_id  | int(11)      |
| 2  | title   | varchar(15)  |
+----+---------+--------------+
```

I need to get the `11` after `int(` given above.
I am using CodeIgniter 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `mysqli_fetch_field($result)`, this returns exactly what you want.
Pass your query result set to this function. This is in php, in codeigniter use
`$this->db->field_data('table_name')`. Hope it helps.

Comment: let me check that.